# Azure Key Vault: AADSTS700024: .NET Core, Linux Container. Client assertion is not within its valid time range

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I've been having trouble connecting to Azure Key Vault from a ASP .NET Core app running inside docker container.

The app is using clientID/Certificate to authenticate with the vault.
I have made an app registration and granted permission to it for using the vault.

When I run the app inside docker I keep getting this error:

> Unhandled exception. Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS700024: Client assertion is not within its valid time range. Current time: 2020-03-11T00:06:34.4692395Z, expiry time of assertion 2020-03-10T11:40:33.0000000Z.

```
NuGet: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault v3.1.2
Nuget: Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault v.3.0.5
NuGet: Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication v1.0.3
NuGet: Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory v3.14.2
```

Here is how the vault is configured inside **ConfigureAppConfiguration**

```
X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
collection.Import(path, pwd, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);

var cert = collection[0];

config.AddAzureKeyVault(
                         vault,
                         clientId: builtConfig["ApplicationId"],
                         certificate: cert);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the time in the Docker container is not synchronized. Some ASP.NET images have this issue: [3168](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3168)

You may check the time zone and date by:

```
# Replace the image with yours
docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803 powershell

# Then check timezone and date in powershell 
Get-Timezone
Get-Date
```

Comment: I was using the linux alpine runtime image in my case, however the problem was the time drift in docker for windows. The problem went away after restarting the docker engine/vm. This is an extremely frustrating issue, hope it gets resolved properly. What happens is every time you machine is suspended and resumed the clock in the docker vm doesn't sync the current time, but continues from where it left off.